# AngularJS — Passing object/object property to be $watched into $scope.$watch

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

Deep watching on large objects a performance killer—so I'd like to be able to pass a dynamic object/property into the `watchExpression` parameter of the $scope.$watch function, whenever you invoke an action that changes that particular object or property.

I also have a bunch of different objects and don't want to set up watches for all of them.

For example:

```
var watchingFunction = function (objectToBeWatched) {
    $scope.$watch(function (objectToBeWatched) {return objectToBeWatched;}, function(newValue, oldValue) {
        if (newValue !== oldValue) {...};
}, true);

$scope.object = true;
$scope.changeMyObject = watchingFunction(object);
```

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="object" ng-change="changeMyObject()">
```

I believe this wouldn't work because invoking the function `watchingFunction()` only runs `$scope.$watch()` once? Where as if you define `$scope.$watch` on the `$scope` (instead of wrapped inside the `watchingFUnction()`  it is continually watching $scope.$watch's `watchExpression`?

If this is the case, are there any creative things you can do to return a value from `watchExpression` which takes an outside parameter instead of explicitly declaring the object within `$scope.$watch`'s  `watchExpression`?

Thanks a bunch!

**EDIT** Additional clarity—I'm using the `$scope.$watch` to make `$scope.$broadcast`'s to another scope every time a value on the current scope changes.

Comment: I'm confused. If you know that something is changing (like, with `ng-change`), then you don't need a $watch. What are you actually trying to achieve? What is the use case?

Comment: Great point! — Slightly overthought that... :-P I updated the question with an edit at the bottom. Thank you.

Comment: Ok, but now why do you need to re-assign the watched expression?

Comment: Would a typical use-case for this to be to pass multiple objects into the same ```$scope.$watch```?

Comment: I don't understand what your use case is. I suggest you edit the question and clarify with a small illustrative example what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Will try to clean it up. Thanks for the help thusfar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `$scope.$watch` [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope) states `watchExpression` is called multiple times (even in one digest cycle), but if you passed object there and you change this object to another then it will not work. That is why it is better to pass string watchExpression

```
$scope.$watch('object', function() {...} )
```

or change what is inside object.

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="object.value" ng-change="changeMyObject()">
```

Comment: Maybe explicitly worth to mention in your post that ``$scope.$watch`` also supports nested object watching, that is ``$scope.watch('object.nestedobject.property', function () {...})``